# how to detect a tab/window close event and then show a customized overlay with jqueryui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, dom-events

I want to detect a tab/window close event (excluding <kbd>F5</kbd> refreshing and link-click event and so on) and then show a overlay. I found some answer online which is like this:

```
    endSession: function() {
        //customized overlay goes here
    },

    wireUpEvents: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.validNavigation = false;
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            if (!self.validNavigation) {
                    self.endSession();
                    return "bye"; // Chrome needs a returned string to fire the event
            }
        }
        $('html').bind('keypress', function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 116) {
                self.validNavigation = true;
            }
        });
        $('a').bind("click", function(){
            self.validNavigation = true;
        });
        $('form').bind('click', function(){
            self.validNavigation = true;
        });
        $('input[type=submit]').bind('click',function(){
            self.validNavigation = true;
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        wireUpEvents();
    });
```

But I just found two weird things:

1. The <kbd>F5</kbd> keypress event cannot be detected, it can only detect those number and character keypress event. And what surprised me the most is that it is the character t instead of F5 which has keyCode == 116! (it seems that 116 is the ascii code for lowercase t)
2. As Chrome needs a returned string to fire the event, it always shows a default popup with the string in it when it fires, which means I cannot create my customized popup with jqueryui or something. How to fix this?